# Click event is not working in IE but works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angular, internet-explorer, onclick

Here is the html code where i've added the click event which points to a function and the function will alert some message.

```
<div class="horizontal-align" *ngFor="let taxId of selectedTaxIds">
    <button class="btn btn-rounded" disabled *ngIf="taxId.Tin !== 'All'">
         <span >Taxi ID: </span>
         <span class="text-semibold pl-4"> {{ taxId.Tin }} </span>
         <div class="close-btn" (click)="newfun()" >
              <mat-icon class="icon-display"  svgIcon="close"></mat-icon>
         </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

```
newfun(){
alert('some message')
}
```

This is working fine with chrome but not in IE. I tried declaring a id to a tag and selecting the id with document.getElementById method that is working fine. Even while inspecting the code i can see the click event in the IE developers tool event tab.
Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check button definition in [HTML5 standart](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

> Content model: Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive
>   content descendant.

According to your code, you want to click the child elements inside the button element, it will not work in IE browser.

I suggest you modify your code as below (add click event to button element, instead of the div tag):

```
<div class="horizontal-align" *ngFor="let taxId of selectedTaxIds">
    <button class="btn btn-rounded" disabled *ngIf="taxId.Tin !== 'All'" (click)="newfun()">
         <span >Taxi ID: </span>
         <span class="text-semibold pl-4"> {{ taxId.Tin }} </span>
         <div class="close-btn" >
              <mat-icon class="icon-display"  svgIcon="close"></mat-icon>
         </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

Besides, you could also change the button element to div tag, like this:

```
<div class="horizontal-align" *ngFor="let taxId of selectedTaxIds">
    <div class="btn btn-rounded" disabled *ngIf="taxId.Tin !== 'All'">
         <span >Taxi ID: </span>
         <span class="text-semibold pl-4"> {{ taxId.Tin }} </span>
         <div class="close-btn" (click)="newfun()" >
              <mat-icon class="icon-display"  svgIcon="close"></mat-icon>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```